# How to compare the date and get last date which should not be today date

Tags: php, arrays, date, multidimensional-array

I am having a array of client visits information.. Array is having the visits in ascending 
order date.. I need to get the last visits.. But it should not be today.

```
    stdClass Object
     (
        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [ID] => 39334
                                [ClassID] => 3193
                                [StartDateTime] => 2013-04-29T06:00:00
                                [LateCancelled] => 
                                [EndDateTime] => 2013-04-29T06:45:00
                           )
         [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [ID] => 39334
                                [ClassID] => 3193
                                [StartDateTime] => 2013-04-30T06:00:00
                                [LateCancelled] => 
                                [EndDateTime] => 2013-04-30T06:45:00
                           )
     )
```

Here I want to get the first one...
There can be any number of visits. I have showm only two...

Comment: The easiest way to filter these results would be in the query that is getting them from the database.  If you provide that query we can help you adjust it to filter them how you would like.

Comment: in query add condition WHERE StartDateTime<CURDATE()

Comment: No this is an api resoponse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$whatIneed = false;

foreach($myObj as $obj){

    // If this is today object just break, and object from previous loop is what you need
    if(date('dmY')==date('dmY',strtotime($obj->StartDateTime))) break;

    // saving object in loop into variable
    $whatIneed = $obj;
}

print_r($whatIneed);
```

Comment: @Waygood you're right, added some comments... Also there was mistake - break need to be before saving object. Fixed it too.

Comment: @Narek +1 for complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function or method to sort your array of objects. It must receive array of objects as a parameter, then, for example, create another one, and add objects there one by one, first - the latest, starting from midnight and back, then second...

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($obj as $valobj){
   // if curentdate is greater than db visit date then insert into array    
   if(strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) > strtotime(date('Y-m-d',$valobj->StartDateTime))){
            $arr[] = $valobj;
   }

}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Also as robert said we can also filter it out using mysql query like 'where visitdate!=curdate()'